# Filter response weighted formula representation

Tags: filters, filter-design

I am trying to represent a filter response numerically using the formula shown in the end. I know its electromagnetic response.

Could you please help me understand how to make in Matlab such filter response photo shown below using the $Y_n$ and coefficients?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What prevents you from just implementing the formula as written in Matlab ? What other constraints do you have?